# MFC frame application not repainting when covered or shaken

Tags: mfc

I am creating a MFC frame based application for instrument monitoring/plotting/interaction, with several child windows hosted in a main frame. These child windows are all created by the main frame using:

```
MakeCommandsWindow("Child Window",   
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
            CommandsRect, this, NULL);
```

which calls this construtor:

```
BOOL Commands::MakeCommandsWindow(LPCSTR WindowTitle, DWORD dwStyle,
                  RECT& rect, CWnd* pParent, UINT nID){
CString CommandsWindowClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(
             CS_DBLCLKS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ,
             AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW));
CWnd::Create(CommandsWindowClass, WindowTitle, dwStyle,
             rect, pParent, nID);
```

The application works well except in its handling on repaint events. When the application is covered by another window, and uncovered, it does not redraw properly. In addition, it does not maximize or resize properly. My understanding is that MFC automatically sends redraw messages during these events, and that I should not have to intercept these messages. I have implemented some manual redraw() instructions after modal dialogs close to handle some of these issues so far, but I do not know what is the proper way to handle this deeper problem, or what aspect of my application is incorrect. 
Thank you, any advice appreciated.

Edit: the Redraw() mentioned:
    After a dialog (which covers the centerwindow) closes, I tell the center window to repaint:
    PlotSettings Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();
    MonitorWindow->RedrawWindow();

Comment: When the application is covered by another window and uncovered, the uncovered windows will have an "invalid" client area, and will thus be receiving `WM_PAINT` messages. In response to this message the window procedure should paint its client area (the whole area, or just the invalid part, if you want to provide an "optimized" version). But in the code you have posted there is no window procedure, nor handling of `WM_PAINT` messages. How did you  "implement some manual redraw() instructions"? Make them a function (taking a `hDC` as a parameter) and call it in `WM_PAINT` processing as well.

Comment: Thank you Constantine. My understanding was that MFC doesnt usually have an explicit Window Procedure, just the message maps. Added the redraw part in the question.  I do have OnPaint() handlers for the windows, but just the basics: void CPlot::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.SetBkMode(OPAQUE);
}

Comment: Calling RedrawWindow() with no parameters (default rect, region and flags, see doc) causes a full repaint. Normally you do not need to do this, unless there is a cpu-intensive operation following and you want an immediate repaint. The WM_PAINT message is low-priority (amongst the last ones to be processed). What do you do in MonitorWindow::OnPaint()? I would suggest adding a small beep sound there (eg Beep(500,50)), to see when it's called. It should be called when the window has an invalid area and needs to be repainted - paint the window there.